# How can I know if the mouse is over the header row in a WPF ListView?

Tags: wpf, listview, coordinates

I'm implementing simple drag-and-drop functionality in my app, and I would like to know if the user has dropped the item above the first item in the list (in the header row) so i can just insert it as the first item.

I'm using `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` to get the item at the drop position, but this only works if there actually is an item there.

```
HitTestResult hitTestResults = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(myListView, location);
```

When the mouse is on the headers i get one of many several items in `hitTestResults.VisualHit`. In just a few tests, I've gotten `ListBoxChrome`, `TextBlock`, and `Border` How can i know if any of these are part of the header row? I can't just test for them specifically since there could be other UI elements returned.

Can i get the coordinates of the header row of the listview to see if my point is inside it? Or is there a way that i can know if my Point is inside that header row?

Comment: I don't see why `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` shouldn't return the Header item as well (probably a `TextBlock` in a `Border`). Can you add some sample code reproducing your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know how your current implementation look but you can walk up the Visual Tree until you either find a `ListViewItem` or a `GridViewColumnHeader`. If you find a `GridViewColumnHeader` you know that the item was dropped in this specific Header.

*Uploaded a small sample project here demonstrating the effect with `MessageBox`'s on drop:* http://www.mediafire.com/?v3l8nl4rnewhz5s

It will look something like this

```
private void ListView_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    ListView parent = sender as ListView;
    YourDataClass data = e.Data.GetData(typeof(YourDataClass)) as YourDataClass;
    if (data != null)
    {
        HitTestResult hitTestResult = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(parent, e.GetPosition(parent));
        ListViewItem hitItem = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualParent<ListViewItem>(hitTestResult.VisualHit);
        GridViewColumnHeader columnHeader = VisualTreeHelpers.GetVisualParent<GridViewColumnHeader>(hitTestResult.VisualHit);
        if (hitItem != null) // ListViewItem Drop
        {
            //..
        }
        else if (columnHeader != null) // Header Drop
        {
            //..
        }
    }
}

public static T GetVisualParent<T>(object childObject) where T : Visual
{
    DependencyObject child = childObject as DependencyObject;
    while ((child != null) && !(child is T))
    {
        child = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
    }
    return child as T;
}
```